# (Unknown education) in completeness report

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

Importing my high school from LinkedIn fails as the entry doesn't show up on my profile once the import is said to be completed. The failed entry is somehow recorded though as it is shown as `(Unknown education)` on the `completeness report` page as shown in the image. I tried to import the education entry 3 times, so there are 3 *(Unknown education)* entries. I'm redirected to my profile if I click on *(Unknown education)*, but still it is not shown on my profile, so I can't edit or delete it.

Also when searching for myself using the employers test-drive of `candidate search` I find myself listed with 6 education entries, while my profile shows 3 education entries.

[image: (Unknown eduction) in completeness report]

Comment: The same issue happened to me. There is at least "unknown" education item I cannot edit or delete.

Comment: For me it's fairly accurate, still can't figure out what exactly happened in high school.